# no Get More in Plugin Manager in qgis 2 + ubuntu 13.04

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

After upgrade of qgis 1.8 to qgis 2.0 I couldn't find the choice "Get more" in Plugin Manager and I can't install plugins.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what the plugin installer looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, it was a conflict betwween a package and qgis-Python wich I couldn't install qgis-Python. But unfortunatelly I don't remember the name of file. I uninstall this file and then I install qgis-python. It was something with *sql* in the body of names programm. The name of this programm you can find in error message when you try to install qgis-python.

Answer (score 15):

Please make sure that you have the same version for *qgis* and *python-qgis*.

```
dpkg -l | grep qgis
```

It you update qgis from the ubuntugis-nightly repository, for example, you also need to update *python-qgis* and *python-qgis-common*. There is no explicit depedency, so you might end up with different versions for *qgis* and *python-qgis*.

In my Ubuntu 12.04.3, I was not able to get more plugins, because I had:

```
ii qgis 2.1.0+git20131011+4cb37b1~precise-ubuntugis1 
ii qgis-common 2.1.0+git20131011+4cb37b1~precise-ubuntugis1
ii libqgis2.1.0 2.1.0+git20131011+4cb37b1~precise-ubuntugis1             
but also:
ii python-qgis 2.0.1-2+precise1
ii python-qgis-common 2.0.1-2+precise1
```

Doing

```
sudo apt-get install python-qgis python-qgis-common
```

solve my problem and might solve yours.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.

As suggested above I looked at the different versions using this command in the terminal.

dpkg -l | grep qgis

Then instead of using "apt-get" I used "aptitude". The following command upgraded all the qgis version to the latest.

sudo aptitude upgrade

This worked for me, now I have access to all my plugins again.