# How can I get the plugin manager "get more" icon?

Tags: qgis, plugins, windows-7

I am fairly new to QGIS and i was looking to add more plugins to the core provided in version 2.0 
I read the user manual provided by QGIS and found out that there should be an icon "get more" available in plugin manager. Actually in the QGIS version i am using (2.0.1 Dufour) I can only see two icons: installed and settings.
How can i get the get more one? Any suggestion?
In addition, if i go in settings the status of the plugin repositories is unavailable. Is this "normal"?

I have checked [no Get More in Plugin Manager in qgis 2 + ubuntu 13.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72921/no-get-more-in-plugin-manager-in-qgis-2-ubuntu-13-04?lq=1) but I get a diffeterent window for the settings.

[image]

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Hi Mapperz,i am using windows 7

Comment: I'm noticing this too on Ubuntu 12.04...

Comment: the question is how can i check in windows that i am using the correct python?

Comment: Is your computer behind a proxy? QGIS cannot connect to the plugin repository.

Comment: mmm maybe, i will ask the IT support. Thanks for the advice i will investigate. In case the computer is behind a proxy, what should i do then? Thank you!

Comment: Underdark....just to let you know that the problem has been solved! thank you for pointing in the right direction :)

Comment: @ilariamarengo please mark the answer as accepted so that the question can be closed http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @ilariamarengo what are the proxy setting and how do i add it in QGIS

Answer (score 2):

If your computer is behind a proxy QGIS cannot connect to the plugin repository without the correct settings.

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted so that the question can be closed: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @AndreJ not sure Ilaria can see your comment if you don't @ her

Comment: @underdark what are the proxy setting and how do i add it in QGIS