# regarding to manage and install plugins not access

Tags: qgis-plugins, installation

I am a new QGIS user and I am trying to add the qgis2leaflet plugins. I went into 'Manage and Install Plugins'. However, whenever I try to search for the plugin, it never shows up as on option. In the dialog box I wrote out 'qgis2leaflet' and no option show in plugin manager for uninstall and reinstall. [image]

Comment: Can you provide more information about your OS (windows, Linux,...), the QGIS version you install and any others information. It seems that the problem is related to your python installation. You can have a look to these links https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72921/no-get-more-in-plugin-manager-in-qgis-2-ubuntu-13-04 or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/106936/python-support-with-qgis-2-4-on-ubuntu-14-04 which provides answers for Qgis 2.0 on Ubuntu. You can also try a research on Google or others with the message you get on your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this tutorial ([link](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/leaflet_maps_with_qgis2leaf.html)) you can read:

> qgis2leaf plugin is no longer in active development. The functionality of this plugin is folded into a new plugin called
>   qgis2web.
>
> See [Web Mapping with QGIS2Web tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html) for an updated version of this
>   tutorial.

Then, try that plugin instead.